# How to open root files (ROOT Framework)

Tags: file, frameworks, analysis, root-framework

How to open .root file in C++ code ? and read and print parameter from .root file using C++ code on terminal ?

Answer (score 3):

you need to install ROOT (https://root.cern.ch/)

then you have couple of options, the simplest is opening it in the interpreter by simply typing in the console:

```
root your_file.root
```

and you can look at it in the Browser, type in :

```
TBrowser b
```

to open it from a script/C++ code and get the tree stored in it:

```
#include "TFile.h"
#include "TTree.h"

TFile *f=new TFile("your_file.root");
TTree *tr=(TTree*)f->Get("the_tree_name");
```

Comment: In that case you can retrieve the object using: TFile *f=new TFile("your_file.root"); TH1F *h=(TH1F*)f->Get("hM0");

Comment: Is there a way to not having to use the command line?
I need to inspect lots of root files for my thesis and want to open the TBrowser by double clicking a root file. But it does not work. Does anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Well, I believe the second part of the answer is exactly that. If you prefer python look up pyROOT.

Comment: I don't want to import the data into a script. 
Root has the TBrowser, which is a GUI that shows you the content of Root files as histograms.
But to open the TBrowser I first have to start Root from the command line and then call the constructor for a new TBrowser. In the TBrowser GUI I can then navigate to the file I want to inspect and then I can open the hisograms.

Comment: This is a really tedious and unnecesarily complicated process. What I want is to be able to see the TBrowser histograms by double clicking on a root file. Just like when you want to read a PDF file you double click on it and can immediately start reading. Why is it not that simple for Root files?

Answer (score 2):

If you are restricted to the terminal (i.e. no access to X server), then you can use something like

```
root -l myfile.root
root [0] .ls
<...>
KEY: TTree tree;1 Demo ntuple
root [1] tree->Scan("parameter")
```

(see [section 11](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuide.html#viewing-the-logical-file-contents) of the root user's guide).

Depending on the type of the parameter you want to print, you might also want to consider `myObject->Print()` (hit `myObject->[tab]` from your root command-line session).

If you can use a graphical user interface (e.g. `ssh -Y`), then the answer from @asen-christov is the way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to directly open the TBrowser from the GUI without having to open the commandline?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just save a file (for example try.cpp)
Then at the terminal I just type `root -l try.cpp`
Print and Scan (as shown in the above answer) prints what you need.

TBrowser b shows you what is inside the .root file (the Tree and branches and leaves)